# Sed-replacing a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have below code:

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" width="74">
<p align="center">server1</p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" width="74">
<p align="center">server2</p>
</td>
```

and so on.I want to get output as:

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" width="74">server1</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" width="74">server2</td>
```

What should be my approach?Say for example the file is server.html
I have done something like this:

```
sed "s/<p align="center">*</p>/*/" -i server.html
```

But its not working.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Have you tried this on the command-line first?  You may also need to use /g on the end to replace multiple results per line.

Comment: thank you ulmangt,ghoti and Lev.Command provided by @ulmangt work like a charm.but I really apprecaite Ghoti's approach.Do I have an option to choose multiple answer here?

Comment: You can accept only one, but feel free to upvote everything you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use regular expressions with sed, you can reference the Xth matched `()` block with `\X`

Also, with all those slashes running around in your expression, I would use `|` as your sed delimiter just to make the expression a little less opaque.

```
sed -e "s|<p align=\"center\">\(.*\)</p>|\1|" server.html
```

Comment: You can also avoid escaping your double quotes by using single quotes.  `sed -e 's|<p align="center">\(.*\)</p>|\1|' server.html`

Answer (score 2):

Once again someone's parsing HTML with regular expressions... Well, the following command seems to work with the particular example you posted:

```
sed -re 's/<p align="center">(.*?)<\/p>/\1/g'
```

However, it will break if any tiny bit changes, consider using an HTML parser.

EDIT: without regex, the following can be done with the same result:

```
sed -e 's/<p align="center">//g' -e 's/<\/p>//g'
```

But it's even dirtier than the first one.

Comment: HTML paser in Shell?Can you give me abit hint?

Comment: and also my bad..I am using AIX.so no sed -r :(

Comment: Not in bash, I guess. Personally, I'd use Python, at least if I had to make changes to more than one file. `sed` really depends on how each line looks. What if your `<p>` tag is closed on the next line, not on the same one?

Comment: Actually the same can be done without `-r` as well, as ulmangt shows.

Answer (score 2):

This is your command line...

```
sed "s/<p align="center">*</p>/*/" -i server.html
```

Problems:

1. You're specifying your commands before your options, and not identifying the command with a `-e` option.  (Not sure if sed in AIX minds.)
2. You're not matching text with a valid regular expression.
3. The close-paragraph has an unescape slash which is being treated as a delimiter.
4. Your replacement string is just an asterisk.

I wouldn't use sed for this.  While you might be able to come up with an arcane, unreadable script to handle this using GNU sed, it probably wouldn't be portable, and you wouldn't be able to read it 30 minutes after you wrote it, if you're not intimately familiar with sed and regexes.

You could output something equivalent to what you're asking with this:

```
sed '/<p/s#<[^>]*>##g' server.html
```

There are usually issues handling HTML with regular expressions, but if you're just dealing with guaranteed-predictable text, AWK may be a reasonable solution for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^<td/ { line=$0; }
/^<p/ { gsub(/<[^>]*>/,""); line=line $0; }
/^<\/td/ { print line $0; }
```

Note that this is not the most elegant awk script that could be written; things are spelled out more fully than they need to be so that you can see the kind of pattern matching it normally does, so you can adjust it to suite different HTML.

An alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { ORS=""; }
/^<p/ { gsub(/<[^>]*>/,""); }
{ print; }
/^<\/td/ { printf("\n"); }
```

The other thing you could look at is changing the behaviour of a `<p>` inside a `<td>` using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a regular expression to manipulate HTML isn't the best way.  You should look into an HTML parsing library and write code to transform the HTML after it has been parsed.

Comment: You are 100% right.But in this case regular expression is a safe bet cause the file will not change.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^<td nowrap="nowrap" width="74">$/{N;N;s/\n[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<\/p>\n/\1/}' file
<td nowrap="nowrap" width="74">server1</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" width="74">server2</td>
```